# Google App Engine using Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I want to create a web application on GAE. Due to portability concerns I prefer to use Django instead of webapp2. Django also has more libraries and tools available.

I prefer to avoid using the Cloud SQL database due to pricing issue (I want to start free).

Google has a [tutorial on this configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel)

Thing is, this is an old document (Nov 2010), and django-nonrel may not be supported anymore according to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926403/easiest-way-to-get-django-working-on-google-app-engine)

In addition, the django-nonrel installation instructions got me nowhere, which reinforce this obsolecense assumption.

A couple of questions:

- Is running django app on top of GAE with the non-relational db still a recommended option?
- Is there a recent tutorial on how to get started with this option?

Comment: it's all here now: https://github.com/django-nonrel and it's still going. http://django-nonrel.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need django-nonrel to work with django and appengine. If you're fine with using dastore / ndb models in place of of djangos model.Model then that's the route I would go.

A couple old tutorials here:

- http://thomas.broxrost.com/2008/04/08/django-on-google-app-engine/
- https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django-guestbook/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdjangoguestbook